# GTK configure error

Tags: gtk, configure

On running:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk
```

I receive the following error at message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.33.1    atk >= 2.5.3    pango >= 
1.30.0    cairo >= 1.10.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.10.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.26.0) were
not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.33.1' but version of GLib is 2.32.3
Requested 'atk >= 2.5.3' but version of Atk is 2.4.0

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

I have already installed libgtk2.0-dev based on similar answers to questions similar to this one, but this hasn't helped.

```
 apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

I'm on an Ubuntu 12.04.
GTK-version: gtk+-3.6.4

Please help.

Comment: What version of gtk+ are you compiling?

Comment: @Nelson added version to post, gtk+-3.6.4

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/210195/how-to-update-from-gnome-3-4-1-to-3-6

Answer (score 0):

You're using GTK 3 and installed development packages for GTK 2. Guess what? It won't work.
`apt-get install libgtk3.0-dev` (or similar, I don't use Ubuntu, hence don't know the exact package name) should fix your problem.

Comment: no, that's not true, gtk 3 requires installation of the older library as well

Comment: No, GTK 3 doesn't require the installation of GTK 2. Installing GTK 3 development packages on any good distro will pull the right dependencies, but shouldn't pull GTK 2.